# Working fine on localhost but on live (1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Got stuck with this error:

> (1/1) TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68).

Project is working fine on the localhost server but on my live server it's getting `Tokenmistach exception`. I have done a lot of research, but everything seems like I did earlier in the project.

For example :-

```
 -- Inside form {{ csrf_field() }}

-- meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"

-- Permissions is also correct. also i have checked with cleared cookies.
```

Please do help me I will be thankful to you expert guys. I am getting stuck with this. Little frustration in my mind now.

If you want to check the live url: `http://pullist.testingwebsitedesign.com/`

Comment: It could be a problem with your sessions. The token gets saved to your session and by default it shouldn't regenerate on every page load.

Comment: I ve also checked the session file it's correct as now. but still dont know why the problem is arising.

Comment: You can try remove SESSION_DOMAIN from your .env and set SESSION_DRIVER=file then do: php artisan cache:clear then `php artisan config:clear

Comment: seems fine for me. I tried it with your provided url

Comment: My requested token and session tokens seems like different           array:2 [▼
  "SessionToken" => "5PXghiDlPI5C6b8kNPw2KlavRREC7uMi8uOg4tPX"
  "RequetedToken" => "YeChuQJ2fW04yLnUreC08nGcjGttA121nOYZesBS"
]
 How to fix this?